# Show custom entity bundle field

Tags: entities, configuration, 8

I created an module polls and entity poll using Drupal Console

I want to add default entity_type on installation.
Currently I added only one field to it field_image.

I created following files

FILENAME : **field.field.poll.article.field_image.yml**

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - field.storage.poll.field_image
    - polls.poll_type.article
  module:
    - image
id: poll.article.field_image
field_name: field_image
entity_type: poll
bundle: article
label: Image
description: ''
required: false
translatable: true
default_value: {  }
default_value_callback: ''
settings:
  file_directory: '[date:custom:Y]-[date:custom:m]'
  file_extensions: 'png gif jpg jpeg'
  max_filesize: ''
  max_resolution: ''
  min_resolution: ''
  alt_field: true
  title_field: false
  alt_field_required: true
  title_field_required: false
  default_image:
    uuid: null
    alt: ''
    title: ''
    width: null
    height: null
  handler: 'default:file'
  handler_settings: {  }
field_type: image
```

FILENAME : **field.storage.poll.field_image.yml**

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - file
    - image
    - polls
id: poll.field_image
field_name: field_image
entity_type: poll
type: image
settings:
  uri_scheme: public
  default_image:
    uuid: null
    alt: ''
    title: ''
    width: null
    height: null
  target_type: file
  display_field: false
  display_default: false
module: image
locked: false
cardinality: 1
translatable: true
indexes:
  target_id:
    - target_id
persist_with_no_fields: false
custom_storage: false
```

Field is created but it is coming as hidden in Form. How can I show it when modules get installed.

Please suggest.

--

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure the field in the form display, export this file

```
core.entity_form_display.poll.article.default.yml
```

and put it in the folder /config/install. Remove the uuid line from the yaml file.

Comment: It worked like charm.